# How is memory aligned in the EOSIO smart contract consensus memory?

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index, chainbase

Are there any memory savings if I declare a table record that has, say, a 64-bit integer (occupies 8 bytes) and a 16-bit integer (occupies 2 bytes)? Or is it aligned at 64 bits and said record would consume 16 bytes regardless, instead of hopefully only 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will save 6 bytes per record if you go with the first solution compared to the second one.

Records are stored in the [chainbase](https://github.com/EOSIO/chainbase) and each record consumes the amount of memory used for the entry, depending on the size of the datatypes used.